# Creating custom content panes in VSTO?

Tags: vsto, office-js

Is there any way to create content panes in VSTO similar to the content add-ins in Office.js?

I would like to create content panes with WPF content in them but I was not able to find any equivalent of Office.js' content add-ins in VSTO. Task panes are not enough as I need them to be freely and flexibly positioned by the user inside a document.

I would need them both in Excel workbooks and in PowerPoint slides, preferably in Office 2013, but in Office 2016 would also be suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Task panes (for application-level addins) and Actions Panes (for document-level) are the closest equivalent.